# Python subprocess() wait until the last command in a series command is done

Tags: python, subprocess

Part of my code is shown as follows. The for-loop will kick off a bunch of shell commands that I wanna them to run in parallel. But then, after this for-loop, I have some commands that should only be run if and only if all of those processes fired during the for-loop is done. Is there a way to do that? If I use wait() for every process, then these processes will simply run sequentially, not in a parallel fashion.

```
#split the bedgraph file by chromName
bedfile_list = (options.filename).split(',')
bed1,bed2 = bedfile_list[0],bedfile_list[1]
subgenome_name_list = (options.subgenome_name).split(',')
sub1,sub2 = subgenome_name_list[0],subgenome_name_list[1]
for chromosome in chrom:
    #os.system('grep \'{}\' {} > {}.{}.temp'.format(chromosome, bed1, sub1, chromosome))
    #os.system('grep \'{}\' {} > {}.{}.temp'.format(chromosome, bed2, sub2, chromosome))
    p1 = subprocess.Popen('grep \'{}\' {} > {}.{}.temp'.format(chromosome, bed1, sub1, chromosome),shell=True)
    p2 = subprocess.Popen('grep \'{}\' {} > {}.{}.temp'.format(chromosome, bed2, sub2, chromosome),shell=True)



subprocess.Popen('rm *.temp')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course! Just store your popen objects, then you can check them all for completion before moving on:

```
# create an empty list to add all of the popen objects to
processes = []

for chromosome in chrom:
    p1 = subprocess.Popen('grep \'{}\' {} > {}.{}.temp'.format(chromosome, bed1, sub1, chromosome),shell=True)
    p2 = subprocess.Popen('grep \'{}\' {} > {}.{}.temp'.format(chromosome, bed2, sub2, chromosome),shell=True)

    # stash the popen objects for later use
    processes.append(p1)
    processes.append(p2)

# before moving on, call wait() on all of the objects to ensure they're done
# this is a blocking call, so the loop won't complete until all processes have returned
for p in processes:
    p.wait()

# now do your post processing work
```

Comment: @YileiHuang I'm glad my answer helped. If you found that it correctly answered your question, please consider "accepting" the answer by clicking the grey check mark below the vote buttons. That's how question askers generally indicate the most useful answers on SO. You're not required to accept any answer, but it is nice to do when you receive helpful ones. Some more information: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)